# Limit problem: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{3}}\right)$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

How do I solve it? I tried conjugate multiplication but that failed.

Comment: $$
\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ \sqrt { x+3 } -\sqrt { 3 }  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{ \sqrt { x+3 } -\sqrt { 3 }}\times
\frac{ \sqrt { x+3 } +\sqrt { 3 }}{ \sqrt { x+3 } +\sqrt { 3 }}
=4\sqrt{3}\,\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=?
$$

Comment: "I tried conjugate multiplication but that failed" Hmmm... Did you, really?

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem was like this when I saw:
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ \sqrt { x+3 } -\sqrt { x }  }  } =\frac { 0 }{ 3-0 } =0$$

but i will write here two cases  $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ \sqrt { x+3 } -\sqrt { 3 }  }  } =2\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 2x\left( \sqrt { x+3 } +\sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }  }{ 2x }  } =4\sqrt { 3 } $$

Comment: thanks well yeah it might be to those that practice  but the solution eluded me, the solution matches that in my book the 4 sqrt 3

Comment: @MarkViola,i think it is correct